# Trouble reading file into ctypes structure

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a raw binary file which I'm trying to cast/move into a ctypes structure I've made, but I can't seem to find the right command to do it.

Simplified version of my code:

```py
class Example_Structure(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("a", c_uint16),
        ("b", c_uint16, 14),
        ("c", c_uint16, 2),
        ("d", c_uint16)
    ]

    #reading a file using open() and getting file size

    buf = create_string_buffer(file_size)
    file_object.readinto(buf)
    struct = Example_Structure()      
    memmove(addressof(struct),buf,48) #This is the line I'm unsure about
    # Maybe use cast(buf,struct) ?
    print(struct.a)
```

I usually get `"ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type"` on the `memmove` line when trying this without `addressof(struct)`, but using `addressof` just gives me `0` for every field.

Thanks for your help

EDIT:
I've found some success using this:

```
tmp = cast(addressof(buf),POINTER(struct)).contents
```

Comment: You can `.readinto()` an instance of the Example_Structure directly.  No need for memmove.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the size of your Structure should be 64. But you don't even have to guess. Use `sizeof` so your memmove statement becomes

```
memmove(addressof(struct),buf,sizeof(struct))
```

The nice feature of this is that if you make a change to the fields in Example_Structure, you don't have to go back and compute the size.

Finally, I'd recommend you rename your variable from struct to something else. If you ever decide to use the popular [struct module that is built into the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html), you could get into trouble with naming collisions.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than you think.  `ctypes.Structure` supports the buffer protocol, so you can directly do:

```
buf = Example_Structure()
file_object.readinto(buf)
```

Example:

```
from ctypes import *

class Example_Structure(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("a", c_uint16),
        ("b", c_uint16, 14),
        ("c", c_uint16, 2),
        ("d", c_uint16)
    ]

# Create some raw test data
with open('test.bin','wb') as f:
    f.write(b'\x22\x33\xff\x7f\xaa\x55')

buf = Example_Structure()

with open('test.bin','rb') as file_object:
    file_object.readinto(buf) # Will read sizeof(buf) bytes from file

print(f'{buf.a:04x} {buf.b:04x} {buf.c:04x} {buf.d:04x}')
```

Output:

```
3322 3fff 0001 55aa
```